# How to set environmental variable for a project in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

How to set environmental variable for a project in Xcode 7?

Specifically I am trying to get the COCOS2DX_ROOT variable to work. Xcode seems to ignore any variable I set for the current user, and also any variable I set for the project from the scheme menu>Run>Arguments>"Environment Variables". There I set the var key to `COCOS2DX_ROOT` and value is `/somepath`
Still Xcode refuses to expand the path in Header Search paths.
For instance, I've tried `$(COCOS2DX_ROOT)`, `$COCOS2DX_ROOT`, `${COCOS2DX_ROOT}` and so on, to no success...